# Any Java plugin/code to manage uploaded files?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

According to current requirement,user will upload files with large size,which he may like to download later. I cannot store the uploaded files in DB because the size of files is large and performance will be impacted if I store uploaded files in DB. 
Any one knows any java plugin which provide efficient file management on webserver and maintains the link to file so that the file can be downloaded when the link is requested. Also the code will make sure that user will be able to download only those files which is uploaded by them,they cannot download any file just by modifying the download link etc. I am using spring3 as the framework.

Please suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have write access to the file system why not just save them there ?
you then generate an unique ID and save the hash/file relation in db, you then need to supply the ID to get the file feed from a servlet

Answer (score 0):

Store the file content on a part of filesystem out of web application so you cannot reach it changing the link.

Then you can store on db the path for that file, and return them only if the user has the permissions to read it.

Pay attention, do not store all the file on the same folder, or the number of files could grow too much. So find a way to store them with more folder levels.